# Changing from stylesheet to default style

Tags: c++, qt

I need to change between two styles in my app: custom, stylesheet and default one. I tried to change it by:

```
qApp->setStyle(new QCleanlooksStyle);
```

but it doesn't change the colors, images, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke `setStyleSheet` with an empty string.

```
qApp->setStyleSheet( "" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the style and setting the style**sheet** are two different things.

If you have an application-wide stylesheet, that is, you called QApplication::setStyleSheet(), then you'll need to clear it for your setStyle() function to really have any effect:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet( QString() );
```

If, on the other hand, you have random bits of style set on your individual widgets, then you'll probably have to migrate to a global style sheet first.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank God for StackOverflow. You would think something as fundamental as this would be easier to find in the otherwise excellent Qt documentation.